# Prefunding wallets in HardHat

Tags: wallets, testing, binance, hardhat

I know that Hardhat automatically prefunds each default wallet with ETHs, however I have a few questions with regards to that.

1. How does this prefunding work when I change the network (Say from Binance), or rather what currency does hardhat prefund my wallets with when I do the change?
2. Is there a way to easily prefund wallets with my selected currencies (Say BUSD)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It works exactly the same. The ticker may still show up as ETH, but it is referring to the same baseline currency of the network you're interacting with. In the case of BSC, that's BNB.
2. The question is a bit vague. What do you mean by "currency"? That can mean many things in the cryptocurrency space. I will continue my answer assuming you are referring to ERC-20 tokens, whose equivalent is BEP-20 on BSC.

You can prefund your wallets with an amount of BEP-20 tokens by writing a `beforeEach` hook at the most top-level test case:

```
import fp from "evm-fp";
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { SignerWithAddress } from "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/dist/src/signer-with-address";

// ...

describe("Tests", function() {
    beforeEach(async function() {
        const signers: SignerWithAddress[] = await ethers.getSigners();
        await busd.mint(signers[0].address, fp("100"));
        await busd.mint(signers[1].address, fp("100"));
        await busd.mint(signers[2].address, fp("100"));
        // ...
    }

    // Your tests continued ...
}
```

Note that you will also need an ERC-20/ BEP-20 contract that has minting capability. You can use my [GodModeErc20.sol](https://github.com/paulrberg/contracts/blob/6cd056eac3305f09013890137a45d4b9996d9fa8/contracts/token/erc20/GodModeErc20.sol) for that.

Alternative to doing this before running your tests, you may want to write a [Hardhat task](https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html).